# How to get the number of variable b one less than a?

Tags: c++

My numbers go in order from 0 to 3
But I need the variable b to be less by 1 and not go beyond.

Initially, the number is unknown, after receiving the number it is stored in only one variable, the number cannot be changed, but you need to get another number one less for the other variable.

I need to implement it like this.

```
1 A
0 B

2 A
1 B

3 A
2 B

0 A
3 B

1 A
0 B
```

What I have now

```
int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0;

for (;;)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));


    i = (i + 1) % 4;

    a = i;

    b = i;

    cout << a << " A " << endl;

    cout << b << " B " << endl;

    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: is `b = (i-1)%4` not what you want? Please dont ignore the system trying to tell you how to improve the question. You could for example add some more details (what is the current output of the code? what did you try to fix it? etc..)

Comment: `b=a;` before `a=i;` and remove the `b=i;` should set `b` to the previous value.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: with i == 0, you got b = -1 instead of `3`. it should be `b = (i + 4 - 1) % 4`.

Comment: @mch I like your idea and posted an answer. If you post the same answer I will remove mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the idea of mch.

> b=a; before a=i; and remove the b=i; should set b to the previous value.

```
int main() {
    int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));


        b = i % 4;
        i = (i + 1) % 4;

        a = i;

        cout << a << " A " << endl;

        cout << b << " B " << endl;

        cout << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work :), the fact is that the number is not initially known, it may not be `0`, but for example `3` from the very beginning.
you cannot increase the number by `1`, you can only reduce the number `b` after receiving the number `a`

Comment: @pinki In the example in your question it is given with `int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0;`. Please change the question or ask a new question.

Comment: changed the question

Comment: @pinki I changed the answer.

Comment: At the very beginning, `b` is always `0`

Comment: `b` must go from `a` number and it should not be `0`

Comment: _"the fact is that the number is not initially known"_ what number is not initially known?

Comment: the number `a` is not initially known; it cannot be changed
But the number `b` can be obtained from the number `a` and not otherwise.

Comment: `a` depends on `i` and `b` depends on `a`? Exactly that happens in my answer.

Comment: This is similar to what I need, thanks, but I'm not sure yet, I'm confused.